# Accessing task contents from await

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a method that returns Task< PixelData >.

```
myObject.pixelData = await rootPage.GrabPixelData("mypic.png");
```

I have confirmed (from the debugger) that the method completes (and returns a non-null value), but when execution returns myObject.pixelData remains null.

Stangely, the line immediately after that point is never hit (a breakpoint I set there never stops execution).

Here is the class:

```
public class PixelData
{
    public byte[] sourcePixels;
    public int sizeOfSourcePixels;
    public int imageWidth;
    public int imageHeight;
}
```

Here is the method that gets called:

```
public async Task<PixelData> GrabPixelData(string imageFileName)
{
    if (!ImageDictionary.ContainsKey(imageFileName))
    {
        // doesn't exist yet, so load it
        PixelData pd = await LoadPic(imageFileName);
        ImageDictionary.Add(imageFileName, pd);
    }

    var test = ImageDictionary[imageFileName];

    return ImageDictionary[imageFileName];
}
```

I'm pretty new to async / await, and I can't seem to figure this one out.

Do I need to inherit from a certain interface in the PixelData class? Do I need to cast the result to another type? Why doesn't the very next line ever get executed?

Comment: First, make sure you're not calling `Wait` or `Result` anywhere in your program. If you're sure you're not doing this, could you post a small but complete repro?

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for the tip. No Wait or Result calls. I'll see about the repro.

Comment: Does a breakpoint on line after LoadPic ever trigger if you set it? Perhaps it is LoadPic where the bug is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect the cause is some hidden, arcane aspect of .NET 4.5 or it's a bug.

Anyway, the workaround for me was to make an asynchronous call to load the file into the parent class and then grab it in the next line.

Something like this:

```
await rootPage.LoadPixelData("mypic.png");
myobject.pixelData = rootPage.ImageDictionary["mypic.png"];
loadedFlag = true;
```

Is my layout of the classes a little strongly typed? Yes. That's because XAML wipes out my class every time I switch pages, so I have to store everything in the parent class to avoid reloading.